# How to use \cutout command in shapepar package?

Tags: shapepar

How to use `\cutout` command in shapepar package?
I need a cut on the right side of the page (square format).

Comment: Cutting the right side of the page? Do you need a package for editing margin sizes maybe? If you do, consider `\usepackage[left=.5in,top=.75in,right=.5in,bottom=.75in]{geometry}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please read the manual first. Here is a simple example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{shapepar}

\begin{document}

\cutout{r}(-4em,5\baselineskip)\shapepar{\squareshape}
cut cut cut cut cut cut cut cut cut cut cut cut cut cut cut cut
cut cut cut cut cut cut cut cut cut cut cut cut\par
text text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text text text text text

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there any other package able to cutout or reflow text around shapes/images?

Comment: @skan There is a TeX primitive `\parshape`. And the `shapepar` package is based on it.